# Error GroupBy PHP + MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server

```
$Read->FullRead("SELECT an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.title,"
            . "an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.img,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.status,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.id,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.promo_id,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.tipo_bloco,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.bloco_id "
            . "FROM an_promo_bloco_anexo "
            . "INNER JOIN an_promo_page "
            . "ON "
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id = an_promo_page.pg_id"
            . " INNER JOIN an_promo_page_tipo_blocos ON an_promo_bloco_anexo.tipo_bloco = an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.id "
            . "WHERE an_promo_bloco_anexo.promo_id = :pro AND an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id = :pi"
            . " AND an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_tipo = :pt ORDER BY an_promo_bloco_anexo.ordem, an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.title"
            . " AND GROUP BY "
            . "an_promo_page_tipo_blocos,"
            . "an_promo_bloco_anexo"
            . "", "pro={$PromoId}&pi={$p['pg_id']}&pt={$p['pg_tipo']}");
```

Result:

protected 'message' => string 'SQLSTATE[42000]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Column 'an_promobar.promo_title' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.' (length=217)

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Just a suggestion - try and use aliases for tables and it will make your SQL a lot more readable.

Comment: The error message gives enough information to try to resolve it yourself first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `GROUP BY` you need to group by all the fields that you are not using an aggregate function against (ie: `SUM`, `MAX`, etc).

`GROUP BY` is also not part of a `WHERE` clause; it stands alone.

Given your query has no aggregate functions, I don't see why you're using `GROUP BY` at all.

Try this.

```
$Read->FullRead("SELECT an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.title,"
        . "an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.img,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.status,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.id,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.promo_id,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.tipo_bloco,"
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.bloco_id "
        . "FROM an_promo_bloco_anexo "
        . "INNER JOIN an_promo_page "
        . "ON "
        . "an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id = an_promo_page.pg_id"
        . " INNER JOIN an_promo_page_tipo_blocos ON an_promo_bloco_anexo.tipo_bloco = an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.id "
        . "WHERE an_promo_bloco_anexo.promo_id = :pro AND an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_id = :pi"
        . " AND an_promo_bloco_anexo.pg_tipo = :pt ORDER BY an_promo_bloco_anexo.ordem, an_promo_page_tipo_blocos.title"    
        . "", "pro={$PromoId}&pi={$p['pg_id']}&pt={$p['pg_tipo']}");
```